# Mirroring screen

Tags: display

http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=470381Capturedu20160412130115.png

I've accidentally blocked the button, I don't know how.

And I tried to launch this command :

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --pos 0x0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60
```

But it's not working.

Does someone know the command to enable the button "Show the same image on all screens", I don't see on the bottom-left corner of the window ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: How do did you block the button.What did you do last

Comment: I just disable it... ^^ And now, I can't change it.

Comment: But last time, I succeed to mirror my screen using the command I showed.

Comment: How did you disable it?

Comment: I just pressed the button.

Comment: What button did you press?

Comment: "Utiliser cet écran" or "Use this screen"

Comment: The command "xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --same-as eDP1" is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Windows+P to switch between mirrored and extended mode :)

(same shortcut as in Windows ;) )